# Error de inyeccion dependencias WebApi Netcore, c#

Tags: c#, webapi, inyeccion-de-dependencias, netcore

espero me puedan ayudar, tengo un problema al inyectar el context de una bd.
El context y entidades están en un paquete .nupkg independiente del proyecto, entonces los métodos del context son estos:

```
public DbVContext()
        {
        }

public DbVContext(DbContextOptions<DbVContext> options)
    : base(options)
{
}

public DbVContext(string instancia = "db_v", string host = "localhost", string user = "username", string password = "password")
{
    _host = host;
    SetDataConnection(instancia, user, password);
}

private void SetDataConnection(string instancia, string user, string password)
{
    Connection = $"Server={_host}; Database={instancia}; User ID={user}; Password={password}";
}

protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
{
    if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(Connection).EnableSensitiveDataLogging().EnableDetailedErrors();
    }
}
```

y así lo inyecto en el startup.

```
services.AddDbContext<DbVContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("SqlServer")));
```

el error que recibo al ejecutar el api es el siguiente y pues ya no se ejecuta nada, nose porque marca error con el constructor de strings, ademas de que este error sale dos veces en la consola:

```
System.AggregateException: Some services are not able to be constructed (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: CONTEXTV.DbVContext Lifetime: Scoped ImplementationType: CONTEXTV.DbVContext ': Unable to activate type 'CONTEXTV.DbVContext'. The following constructors are ambiguous:
Void .ctor(System.String, System.String, System.String, System.String)
Void .ctor(Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContextOptions`1[CONTEXTV.DbVContext]))
 ---> System.InvalidOperationException: Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: CONTEXTV.DbVContext Lifetime: Scoped Im
plementationType: CONTEXTV.DbVContext': Unable to activate type 'CONTEXTV.DbVContext'. The following constructors are ambiguous:
Void .ctor(System.String, System.String, System.String, System.String)
Void .ctor(Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContextOptions`1[CONTEXTV.DbVContext])
 ---> System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to activate type 'CONTEXTV.DbVContext'. The following constructors are ambiguous:
Void .ctor(System.String, System.String, System.String, System.String)
Void .ctor(Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContextOptions`1[CONTEXTV.DbVContext])
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.CreateConstructorCallSite(ResultCache lifetime, Type serviceType, Type implemen
tationType, CallSiteChain callSiteChain)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.TryCreateExact(ServiceDescriptor descriptor, Type serviceType, CallSiteChain ca
llSiteChain, Int32 slot)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.GetCallSite(ServiceDescriptor serviceDescriptor, CallSiteChain callSiteChain)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngine.ValidateService(ServiceDescriptor descriptor)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngine.ValidateService(ServiceDescriptor descriptor)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider..ctor(IEnumerable`1 serviceDescriptors, ServiceProviderOptions options)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider..ctor(IEnumerable`1 serviceDescriptors, ServiceProviderOptions options)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceCollectionContainerBuilderExtensions.BuildServiceProvider(IServiceCollection services, ServiceProvider
Options options)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.DefaultServiceProviderFactory.CreateServiceProvider(IServiceCollection containerBuilder)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Internal.ServiceFactoryAdapter`1.CreateServiceProvider(Object containerBuilder)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostBuilder.CreateServiceProvider()
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostBuilder.Build()
```

Gracias

Comment: Que es lo que tratas de hacer con ese tercer constructor y ese método SetDataConnection() ?

Comment: `(Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: CONTEXTV.DbVContext Lifetime: Scoped ImplementationType: CONTEXTV.DbVContext ': Unable to activate type 'CONTEXTV.DbVContext'. The following constructors are ambiguous:`... Yup. Repara tus constructores.

Comment: @TheOligarch lo que hace metodo es solo hacer crear la cadena de conexion en string para el !optionsBuilder.IsConfigured del metodo OnConfiguring

Comment: @Arriel pero como?, el primero esta vació el segundo es de DbContextOptions y el ultimo es de strings y el error dice que los metodos que estan mal son el que recibe puros strings y el metodo de DbContextOptions

Comment: @Arthur al setear el servicio ya le estas pasando la cadena de conexion que esta en appSettings.json probablemente, no necesitas construir vos manualmente la cadena de conexion

Comment: no necesitas el constructor que recibe 4 strings..

Comment: @Cmbuffa lo que pasa es que el context es multibase es decir, no siempre se inicializa la base de datos desde el startup, cada instancia de la bd que es distinta por cada cliente, ¿o hay una mejor practica para hace un context que se conecte a múltiples bases de datos y que a su vez tambien se pueda usar con una solo base de datos ?, ese es el fin del constructor de 4 strings si no se inicializa la bd desde startup entonces se inicializara hasta otro punto de ejecucion

Comment: Bueno, lo que pides no es descabellado. A veces es necesario obtener esas cadenas de conexión de manera dinámica. Este [post](https://gavilan.blog/2020/07/09/configuring-entity-framework-core-with-dynamic-connection-strings-asp-net-core/) habla exactamente de lo que deseas hacer. Aquí hay [otro](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/54079.entity-frameworkentity-framework-core-dynamic-connection-strings-c.aspx?WT.mc_id%3DES-MVP-5002204). Suerte

Comment: @Arthur el ejemplo que te paso Arriel te va a servir, yo hice algo parecido hace un tiempo y me base en ese primer link

Comment: @Cmbuffa, Arriel gracias, esta estructura de alguna manera ya lo habia vista e implementado en pruebas, pero lo que quiero es evitar es modificar todos los proyectos pues el context siempre se inicializa con el constructor de 4 string, asi ya estaban estos proyectos

Comment: @Arthur segun esta documentacion https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/dbcontext-configuration/  podes hacer uso de tu constructor, pero tenes que inicializar tu dbcontext con new, sin usar DI, echale un vistazo a ver que tal

Comment: @Cmbuffa gracias, voy a revisar

Answer (score 0):

tu conexion viene de appsetting.json, ya no es necesario agregar `SetDataConnection`,

intenta de esta manera

```
public class DbVContext: DbContext
{

  public DbVContext(DbContextOptions<DbVContext> options) : base(options) { }
  protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
  {
      base.OnModelCreating(builder);
  }

}

//appsettings.json
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "SqlServer": "tu cadena de conexion"
  },
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}


//agregas tu servicio
services.AddDbContext<DbVContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("SqlServer")));
```